# How to map HtmlInputButton in Coded UI testing based on text written on that

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am writing code to make automated Ui testing .

I am working on travel domain.

In my application when i search the car then in next screen the list of all available taxi will shown. now I want to any taxi randomly.
when i record the script then in work as static.when next time I search the car then the amount is changed on HtmlInputButton then playback is failed to locate the control.
I want to click the randomly.
the hire amount is showing on HtmlInputButton like $ 123 next time it will be $ 456 then playback error is showing then i want that clicking is done on the $ base and randomly.

Thanks in advance.
Rajdeep

Answer (score 0):

First Sol: If the buttons arranged in a HtmlTable, loop through all the HtmlRow's of the table and click on the specific HtmlButton contained in that row

Alternate Solution: Edit the search properties of the HtmlInputButton, like "Id" property contains "some value" [Which can be unique with the other HtmlInputButtons Ids]